# Could not connect to development server in genymotion

Tags: react-native, genymotion

I got an issue with Genymotion, searched and tried a lot of ways from google but could not resolved this issue. The problem is two days ago, when I was coding and testing on genymotion, everything worked fine, suddenly, no reason, the red screen showed up.

I tried to clear npm cache, run react-native run-android, react-native start, enter my local IP address to debug server host and port for device, remove node_modules and installed again, remove virtual box, remove genymotion, install all again ... Many ways I tried but no success.

Lucky me, it's still working fine in my real phone, but not really convenient to use real phone to debug.

[image: Red screen error]

Comment: Hi Green Arrow,
Which OS you are using either for development Mac or Windows or linux ?

Comment: Hi Durgaprasad Budhwani, I'm using window 10. I have found one more clue is my genymotion can't connect to the internet, I'm trying to fix that issue first. It could be a root cause.